# Python 3.6 - take a list of different types as input

Tags: python, list, input

If I have an input like: "1 2 3 4 5", I can convert it as list of int as follow:

```
a = input("List: ") #"1 2 3 4 5"
a = list(map(int, a.split())
print(a) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In case we have an input like: "1 2 hello 4 5.0", it's possible to convert it in a list like this: `[1, 2, 'hello', 4, 5.0]` ?

Comment: Not without some extra work to convert the numbers to integers and floats. Or using eval, which people tend to stay away from (since it can do more havoc than good).

Comment: @9769953 That's good advice regarding [`eval`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), but since this is a just a string representing valid Python literals it can be evaluated by `ast.literal_eval`, which doesn't have the security problems of plain `eval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `ast.literal_eval` for this .According to the docs [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) .

It safely evaluates an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display.

```
import ast
a="1 2 hello 4 5.0"

def converter(l):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(l)
    except ValueError:
        return l

print(list(map(converter,a.split())))
```

**INPUT**

```
1 2 hello 4 5.0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 'hello', 4, 5.0]
```

**INPUT**

```
-123 123E123
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[-123, 1.23e+125]
```

Answer (score 3):

Not without some extra work: you'd need your own conversion function that handles the various types. Something like (untested!):

```
def convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return s

list(map(convert, a.split())
```

Comment: FYI, you're missing a close bracket on the last line :-)

Comment: Any reason why you pass on the last error instead of returning `s` in there?

Comment: @BramVanroy For future expansion! (though additional conversions may also happen near the top of the chain). Generally, I just like a clear, final return statement.

Comment: @DavidG Actually, the OP's missing a closing parenthesis there: I copy-pasted that line from the OP, then changed int to convert.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! +1

Comment: If needed `try-except-pass` can be replace with [contextlib.suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress)

Comment: @BramVanroy FWIW, if you move the `return s` inside the `except` block the compiler still adds the bytecode for `return None` to the end of the function, like it always does when a function definition doesn't end in an unconditional return. However, the number of bytecode instructions is identical in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

If you are into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as much as I am, you might want to use something like this (first you should transform the string input into a list with split()):

`a = [int(x) if str(x).isdigit() else float(x) if str(x).replace('.','',1).isdigit() else x for x in a]`

Comment: `if str(x).replace('.','',1).isdigit()` is a bad idea if your floating point strings contain an exponent: "1e50" or "1.23E123".

Comment: And what about negative numbers?

Comment: Of course it's not perfect, it's just a solution to a specific problem. Check this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/23639915/586638